# VSTO ThisWorkbook Property

Tags: excel, vsto

Im currently developing an Addin for MSExcel using Visual Studio Tools for Office, VSTO. Anyway, I am almost done with it, not until I found and encountered an issue.

Currently my C# code, utilizes the ActiveWorkbook propert. But I found out that when another instance of an Excel is open and that specific instance gets the focus, my code will run on that active workbook.

Please see my codes below:

```
  public void AddWorkSheet(string wsName, Excel.XlSheetVisibility visibility)
    {

       Excel.Workbook currentWorkBook =Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
       if (!IsSheetExists(wsName, currentWorkBook))
       {
           Excel.Worksheet newWorkSheet;
           newWorkSheet = currentWorkBook.Sheets.Add();
           newWorkSheet.Visible = visibility;
           newWorkSheet.Name = wsName;
           Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newWorkSheet);
       }
       Marshal.ReleaseComObject(currentWorkBook);
    }
```

What I want to found out is how could I set the workbook to a specific workbook regardless if it is active or not.

Answer (score -1):

As you mention in your question ActiveWorkbook gives you the workbook that you currently have active. Given the name there is nothing unexpected with that.

If you want to add sheets to a specific workbook you obviously should work with the fixed workbook reference. There are several options to use a fixed workbook reference. The easiest would be, if you know the name, to get that specific workbook using its name.

There are so many ways to reference a workbook, just Google a bit and you get examples like this:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/ (it's VBA, but if you have trouble porting that to C# ask a new question specifically to your needs)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering my question. I know VBA has the ability to change the reference workbook using the specified file path, so if I add a new worksheet, regardless if it is active or not. I have it at the top of my mind, but I cannot come up with the right code on how to do this on VSTO add in in C#. Thank you. :)